# Pandas does not separate first two columns when reading in fixed-width file

Tags: python, pandas, fixed-width

I'm trying to read a fixed-width file into Python using Pandas but the first two columns are returned as one.

Here is a sample of the file I am trying to read in:

```
Some header information
          Date            day           value
    01/01/2015         000001           3.14
    01/02/2015              2           1.59
```

and here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd

my_data = pd.read_fwf(my_file, skiprows=1)
```

but upon inspection of `my_data` the first two columns are not separated:

```
> my_data.keys()
array(['Date            day', 'value'])
```

I know that my columns all have a width of 15 characters -- however I have several files with different numbers of columns and the `widths` option seems to expect a *known* number of columns (e.g. `[(0, 15), (16, 30), ...]`) rather an being able to specify the widths but not the number of columns.

Does anyone know how to get pandas to recognize the first two columns are distinct?

Comment: You may get better joy just reading it in as a plain text file: `my_data = pd.read_csv(my_file, skiprows=1, sep='\s+')`

Comment: I edited the data you posted so the code exhibits the behavior you describe. Please check to see if the change is consistent with your real data.

Comment: @unutbu thanks for solving the problem –– apparently this is easily replicated by making the value longer than the header.

Comment: @user12202013: Ah -- that's insightful. It appears the `FixedWidthReader.detect_colspecs` method does not ignore rows specified by `skiprows=1`. A workaround would be to open the file, advance the filehandle to skip the first row, and then pass the filehandle as the first argument to `pd.read_fwf`.